# jQuery video link

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html

I am in need of a widget of jQuery which actually takes the youtube and and store it into the database. I dont want the video uploading widget but I just need a widget which actually takes only you tube link from the user.

I am using HTML 5 and jQuery

Comment: jQuery can't download a video stream and store it in a database. You  will probably need a server side solution for this. If you mean something else, please clarify

Comment: You will need a large database to store the YouTube in it.

Comment: Client-side database, or server-side database? Are you trying to store the video URL in it, or the actual raw video data?

Comment: I am taking the you tube video link for the user and saving the link in my data base using servlet and I am dont want the user to upload the video into database since that will be huge and difficult to manage.I need a interface which actually does this.

Comment: I don't think that you know what you actually want... I'm out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find a front-end solution to a back-end problem.

You say you're using HTML5 and jQuery, but you also need something on the back-end like Ruby on Rails, PHP, Python, etc. for interfacing with the database end of things if all you want to do is store a YouTube link in a database.